# Converting time in hh:mm:ss format to second or minutes

Tags: r

I have a column of time in this format:  **43:46:18**   which shows **hh:mm:ss** (h: hour, m: minutes, s: second), I want to convert this column to seconds (or minutes), but ":" is redundant and I do not know how I should deal with that?

Comment: Questions should supply test data.  I have supplied that for you in the Note in my answer this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lubridate` package contains some useful functions for dealing with dates and times, in particular `hms` is useful for reading times in your format. You could use this as in:

```
library(lubridate)

as.numeric(hms("43:46:18"))
# [1] 157578  #Conversion to seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Define a function which separates the 3 parts of the times into a data frame of 3 columns, converts it to a matrix and then matrix multiplies that with a vector whose 3 components are the number of seconds in an hour, minute and second.  Finally use c(...) to convert that from an nx1 matrix to a plain vector.

To test, apply that to the time column of the test data `dat` defined in the Note at the end.  No packages are used.

```
time2sec <- function(x) {
  c(as.matrix(read.table(text = x, sep = ":")) %*% c(3600, 60, 1))
}

# test using dat from Note at the end
transform(dat, seconds = time2sec(time))
```

giving:

```
  id     time seconds
1  1 43:46:18  157578
2  2 43:46:18  157578
```

**2)** An alternate method is to convert to POSIXlt regarding the hour as a year and then convert that to seconds.  This gives the same result as above.  Again, no packages are used.

```
time2sec_2 <- function(x) {
  with(as.POSIXlt(x, format = "%Y:%M:%S"), 3600 * (year + 1900) + 60 * min + sec)
}

transform(dat, seconds = time2sec_2(time))
```

### Note

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:2, time = "43:46:18")
```